# QGIS attributes disappeared when reopened shapefile

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I'm a new QGIS user so sorry if this sounds lame.

Working in QGIS, I've built a vector layer and added attributes. When I reopened the file this morning, the attributes won't show up in the Attributes table. All I get is a basic 'Feature id' column.

I can see the attributes I added in the DBF file but they wont' show in the table.

I have tried closing and reopening QGIS and aligning projections (WGS84) between by project and layer but nothing working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the right one? The attributes may be turned off, but unless you've done that yourself it's not likely. The columns could be 0 width.. if you start editing and select a feature in the forms view do you see your new attributes?